# Save map annotation using UserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have been searching relentlessly for this solution and left with no choice except to rely on the expertise here on Stackoverflow. I am working on saving a map annotation if the app closes and I have been using the UserDefault to save the annotation.

This is the Objective C code that I found and I tried converting it into Swift and I think there is an error with it. I am not too sure. I place this code at viewDidLoad()

This is the save annotation

```
    var pinnedAnnotation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate)!
    var coordinateData: NSData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: pinnedAnnotation, length: sizeof(pinnedAnnotation), freeWhenDone: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(coordinateData, forKey: pinnedAnnotation)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And I needed a load annotation when the app open.

I dont know if viewDidLoad is the right place to put. Previously I put it in a mapView function of updatingLocation

Edited: Added code for further clarification of what I have done that needed to be corrected

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self as MKMapViewDelegate
    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    tabBar.delegate = self

    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "pinnedAnnotation") != nil {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let pinnedAnnotation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate)!
    let locationData = ["latitude": parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate.latitude, "longitude": parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate.longitude]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(locationData, forKey: "pinnedAnnotation")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    print("Saving data ",  UserDefaults.standard.set(locationData, forKey: "pinnedAnnotation"))

}

 func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if(item.tag == 0){
        if mapView.annotations.count == 1{
            mapView.addAnnotation(parkedCarAnnotation!)

        } else {
            mapView.removeAnnotation(mapView.annotations as! MKAnnotation)
        }
    } 

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? ParkingSpot{
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.animatesDrop = true
        view.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -8, y: -3)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.init(type:.detailDisclosure) as UIView
        return view
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    let locationServiceCoordinate = LocationService.instance.locationManager.location!.coordinate

    parkedCarAnnotation = ParkingSpot(title: "My Parking Spot", locationName: "Find your way back to your car location", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationServiceCoordinate.latitude, longitude: locationServiceCoordinate.longitude))


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking...

For starters when you're saving data to `UserDefaults` the key needs to be a string, I also believe you'll need to save you data in `UserDefaults` as a `Dictionary`

```
let locationData = ["lat": parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate?.latitude, "long": parkedCarAnnotation?.coordinate.longitude]  
UserDefaults.standard.set(locationData, forKey: "pinned_annotation")
```

And then to retrieve the data you would call

```
if let annotationData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "pinned_annotation") as? Dictionary {
    guard let lat = annotationData["lat"], let long = annotationData["long"] else { return }
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
}
```

Now you should hopefully be able to set your annotation with the coordinate

Comment: i think you kinda answer my question but my other half question is, where do I put the codes? I am using mapView and there are plenty functions available. I was told to put it into the func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { }

Comment: You only need to use that if you need to get the user's current location. If that is the case then yes, save the data in that function to save the data every time the user updates their location. As for setting the annotation put it wherever you setup your UI

Comment: I updated my code above, can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen/what didn't happen? So I can see what isn't working

Comment: When I click on the tab bar, it will drop the annotation. Hopefully in this process, it will save the annotation. Now if I force quit the app and reopen the app, the annotation would be gone, but I am hoping to retrieve the annotation using userdefault

Comment: You don't appear to be using the data from the object in `UserDefaults`. You check if it is nil but then just create an empty `MKPointAnnotation`

Comment: Yeah that was the part that I was stucked in and I couldn't figure out what to use